# Multiple Projects in .Net Solution - Combine Build Artifacts from all projects

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, build, msbuild

I have 2 solutions that contain test related code.  One is for UI automation and another for API.  I combined both solutions and I am able to build and run tests from both but:

Each one of those contains similar configs that I would like to combine under one project. No need to have the same thing in both obviously. I removed configs from project2 and created references from Proj1 to Proj2. I build Project1 and artifacts are generated fine from Project1, but it does not contain all artifacts from Proj2.

Previously, when I build projects separately, It would generate say 60 files in the build folder, but now its much less.

Question:
If I decide to add project #3 and add configs to it. How can I build project 3 and combine artifacts from all of them in bin folder of project #3.

I hope I'm making this clear.

Essentially I want to be able to build 1 project which will trigger builds for remaining 2 and pull all artifacts to together.

Comment: Why do not you change build output folder for all projects to common folder. Thats what we do. Our solution has almost 30 projects. Few belong to client and few to server. So we created Client and Server folders and all projects build output maps to one of them.

Comment: Thank you. Good idea. I will try that. Trying to figure out the build sequence as to when you build solution which projects builds first.

Answer (score 2):

As **Ziggler** suggests, you can change the build output folder to combine all artifacts from all of them in bin folder of project #3.

And you can do this by passing `$(OutputPath)` property in command-line. It seems that you're using something like `TeamCity`, `Azure Devops` or what in your environment.

For these tools, we can add msbuild parameter like: `/p:OutputPath="Path to project3's bin folder"` if you're using msbuild to build whole solution(`msbuild xx.sln`). See [Global Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties?view=vs-2019#global-properties).

And about the build order, you can add project dependency to control the build order. Msbuild will recognize project dependency and project reference and then choose the right order automatically. Hope it helps :)

Comment: thank you. Exactly what I was looking for. We use ADO. Thank you

Comment: @ylerner Hi friend, any update for this issue? If my answer helps to resolve your issue,  you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.). And if the issue persists to block you, feel free to let me know and I'm willing to help :)